# SQL Server 2005 with Windows 7 Problems

Tags: sql-server

First of all I restored the database from other server and now all the stored procedures are named as [azamsharp].[usp_getlatestposts]. I think [azamsharp] is prefixed since it was the user on the original server.

Now, on my local machine this does not run. I don't want the [azamsharp] prefix with all the stored procedures.

Also, when I right click on the Sproc I cannot even see the properties option. I am running the SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7.

**UPDATE:**

When I ran the orphan users stored procedure it showed two users "azamsharp" and "dbo1". I fixed the "azamsharp" user but "dbo1" is not getting fixed. When I run the following script:

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'dbo1', 'dbo1'
```

I get the following error:

Msg 15291, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 131
Terminating this procedure. The Login name 'dbo1' is absent or invalid.

Answer (score 2):

A restore done via backup/restore will never ever rename any object in the database. The result of a database restore is the same database that was backed up. If the procedures are named in the restored database [schema].[object] then I guarantee you they were named just the same on the old server too.

What happened most likely is that you weren't aware that on the old server the user you logged in with had an implicit schema associated with it and when you issues statements like `select from table` or `execute usp_foo` you were automatically binded to your default schema.

You must check with the administrator of the old server to kindly tell you the permissions and defaults you had on the system and then ask the adminsitrator of the new server to gratiously restore you the same permissions and defaults.

Comment: how can I find the permissions myself and restore of my local machine? Or is there any option while restoring that it will create users and passwords automatically.

Comment: Your database permissions, and implicitly the default schema are already restored. What you need to do is log in on the new server with exactly the same login you logged in on the old server.

Comment: The new server is my local and it does take any username or password. It is based on windows authentication. The production server where I host my database takes username and password.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx

Comment: Please see my updated post!

Comment: You need to create a login named 'azamsharp'. Is this the login you have been using in the original server? Then you should use this login (with its password) on your new server too. While it is possible to use Windows auth and configure your windows principals in the server and in the database to have the same permissions and default schema as on the old server, this is fairly complex and needs someone experienced to do it. Is much simpler if you create a **SQL login** named 'azamsharp' and use that instead. Make sure you enable mixed authentication.